# Searching a text file and grabbing all lines that do not include ## in python

Tags: python, arrays, file, search, find

I am trying to write a python script to read in a large text file from some modeling results, grab the useful data and save it as a new array. The text file is output in a way that has a ## starting each line that is not useful. I need a way to search through and grab all the lines that do not include the ##. I am used to using grep -v in this situation and piping to a file. I want to do it in python!

Thanks a lot.

-Tyler

Comment: Ok, you say you're trying to write it. Show us what you tried, and what's not working with it.

Comment: Sure, I will add in a bit. I'm not at my PC at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this:

```
fh = open(r"C:\Path\To\File.txt", "r")

raw_text = fh.readlines()
clean_text = []

for line in raw_text:
    if not line.startswith("##"):
        clean_text.append(line)
```

Or you could also clean the newline and carriage return non-printing characters at the same time with a small modification:

```
for line in raw_text:
    if not line.startswith("##"):
        clean_text.append(line.rstrip("\r\n"))
```

You would be left with a list object that contains one line of required text per element.  You could split this into individual words using string.split() which would give you a nested list per original list element which you could easily index (assuming your text has whitespaces of course).

```
clean_text[4][7]
```

would return the 5th line, 8th word.

Hope this helps.

[Edit: corrected indentation in loop]

Comment: Great thanks! I didn't know about the if not line.startswith("##")

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to do the following:

```
listoflines = [ ] 

with open(.txt, "r") as f:     # .txt = file, "r" = read
    for line in f:
        if line[:2] != "##": #Read until the second character 
            listoflines.append(line)


print listoflines
```

If you're feeling brave, you can also do the following, CREDITS GO TO ALEX THORNTON:

```
listoflines = [l for l in f if not l.startswith('##')]
```

The other answer is great as well, especially teaching the .startswith function, but I think this is the more pythonic way and also has the advantage of automatically closing the file as soon as you're done with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I too am using the with open() as f:

Comment: Good man, it's a great habit to have, saves you the trouble of typing f.close() everytime, or the risk of forgetting

Comment: I agree, as you can see, I forgot in the example I gave.

Comment: @Philip Lawrence, don't worry, it happens to the best of us ^_^

Comment: By the way, you do not need the `'r'`, it is that mode by default, and instead of the `for` loop, you can just do: `array = [l for l in f if not l.startswith('##')]`